# Does Java call a method when an object is created at runtime?

Tags: java

I want to set the value of the next array object whenever an object is created in my main function.

This is the object

```
   public class MyObject{
        private int objCount = 0;
        private int i = 0;
        public class Property{..}
        public Property propertyArray[] = new Property[12];
  }
```

Main function creates an empty object and adds properties to the property array.

The object needs to keep different number of properties.

```
   MyObject foo = new MyObject();
   foo.add("ID", 2);
   foo.add("MIE",132);

   MyObject bar = new MyObject();
   bar.add("REV", 22);
```

There is also an array of the object,

```
   public MyObject[] ObjectArray = new MyObject[5];
```

I want to call a method that increases the object array index when a new object is created

Comment: Are you familiar with constructors? If not look them up.

Comment: Also that nested public class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java makes a call when a new object is created, except it's not calling a method, it is calling a constructor. Constructors are declared like methods with no result type, and the name matching the name of the type, i.e. like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private int objCount = 0;
    private int i = 0;
    public class Property{..}
    public Property propertyArray[] = new Property[12];
    // This is the constructor
    public MyObject() {
        ... // <<== Do stuff here
    }
}
```

If you would like to add items to an array inside the `MyObject` class constructor, the array needs to be `static`: although constructors can access instance variables, each constructor gets a brand-new set of instance variables with which to work.

Comment: Actually, they have no return type and the same name as the class.

Comment: @Darkhogg You're right, JLS defines it like that. I got confused with C++ and C# specs, where constructors have the same exact syntax as in Java, but the spec says that they have no name, just a type. The syntax remains exactly the same, though :-)

Comment: +1 technically constructors are special methods in byte code called `<init>`.  The static initialization block is a method called `<clinit>`